# Random Grouping of arrays based on average values in R

Tags: r, random, grouping

I have a data frame given below. The first column is for the IDs of a list of measured values given in the second column. I would like to group IDs ( 8 in each group) into 3 groups randomly many times until the differences between the group Value means would be the smallest, i.e. an ANOVA analysis of the final group means would give a p-value of close to 1.0.

```
ID Value
01F 128.1
02F 196.5
03F 118.3
04F 165.5
05F 105.0
06F 187.5
07F 105.5
08F 148.6
09F 147.2
10F 110.9
11F 109.9
12F 136.5
13F 105.4
14F 196.3
15F 199.2
18F 174.8
19F 138.9
21F 128.1
22F 196.5
26F 187.5
27F 105.5
28F 148.6
29F 147.2
30F 110.9
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your exact measurement of difference in group means. The sum of difference between the absolute value between group *1 and 2*, *1 and 3*, and *2 and 3*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if something like this would work

```
#Initiate data
output = df
output$group = rep(c("grp1", "grp2", "grp3"), each = 8)
p = summary(aov(Value~group, output))[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][1]

set.seed(42)
#Iterate until a suitable output is found
while (p < 0.95){ #Choosing higher value could take more time
    output$group = sample(output$group)
    p = summary(aov(Value~group, output))[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][1]
}

#At this point, 'output' is the answer you want. You can split it by group
split(output, output$group)

#Check p-value
summary(aov(Value~group, output))
#            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
#group        2     41    20.7   0.016  0.984
#Residuals   21  27015  1286.4
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(ID = c("01F", "02F", "03F", "04F", "05F", "06F", 
"07F", "08F", "09F", "10F", "11F", "12F", "13F", "14F", "15F", 
"18F", "19F", "21F", "22F", "26F", "27F", "28F", "29F", "30F"
), Value = c(128.1, 196.5, 118.3, 165.5, 105, 187.5, 105.5, 148.6, 
147.2, 110.9, 109.9, 136.5, 105.4, 196.3, 199.2, 174.8, 138.9, 
128.1, 196.5, 187.5, 105.5, 148.6, 147.2, 110.9)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much d.b. I think this works. Could you list the groups with ID and Values for the best p value? Also, instead of looking for the groups randomized for a p-value, say, <0.9, how about choosing the best set corresponding the maximum p-value out of, say, 50 tries?

Comment: Slight efficiency improvement by changing `output$group = sample(rep(c("grp1", "grp2", "grp3"), each = 8))` to `output$group = sample(output$group)`

Comment: Thank you d.b again. Thank you snoram for the efficiency change.